# Are there "non-standard" streams in Linux/Unix?

Tags: file-descriptors, open-files, standard, streams

The so-called "standard streams" in Linux are stdin, stdout, and stderr. They must be called "standard" for a reason. Are there non-standard streams? Are those non-standard streams fundamentally treated differently by the kernel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, a “stream” is an open file in a process. (The word “stream” can have other meanings that are off-topic here.)

The three standard streams are the ones that are supposed to be already open when a program starts. File descriptor 0 is called standard input because that's where a program is supposed to read user input or its default data input. File descriptor 1 is called standard output because that's where a program is supposed to write its normal data output. File descriptor 2 is called standard error because that's where a program is supposed to write its error messages.

Other file descriptor numbers are not standard anything because they don't have such a preassigned role. They'll end up being used for whatever the program wants. So could call any file opened by a program a “nonstandard stream”, but it would be weird and confusing: “open file other than stdin, stdout or stderr” doesn't really need a name, and “nonstandard stream” sounds like it's some special type of file or a file opened by a nonstandard method, which is not the case.

The conventional role of file descriptors 0–2 is granted by the standard library and by certain programs. For example, console login programs and terminal emulators start the shell (or other program) with the terminal open on these file descriptors. The C standard library creates `FILE*` objects (what C calls streams) for these three standard descriptors. There's no special treatment in the kernel.

Comment: "So could call", did you mean "So you could call"? I was going to ask where these opened files are and if they were accessible to the programmer but then I read "The C standard library creates `FILE*` objects" and I think it's the case: they are the files `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`. Is this correct?

Comment: @uzluisf Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The kernel treats all file descriptors in the same way. It is just a convention to have processes which use file descriptor 0 as the input (stdin), file descriptor 1 as the output (stdout), and print errors on file descriptor 2 (stderr).

When your terminal starts, it creates a pseudo—tty and launches a shell with inputs/outputs assigned to file descriptors 0, 1, and 2. Then if your program doesn’t use this convention, you will have to redirect appropriately the inputs and/or outputs.